# Good way of implementing more windows in PyQt

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt4

How to open a new window after the user clicks a button is described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21414775/1898982

and here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13519181/1898982

```
class Form1(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_Form1):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        self.window2 = None

    def handleButton(self):
        if self.window2 is None:
            self.window2 = Form2(self)
        self.window2.show()

class Form2(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_Form2):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

I want to develop a GUI application that consists of several steps. Once the user clicks next, the current window closes and another window opens. Technically I can do this like it is described above: Each window opens a new one. After a few steps this is pretty much nested.

Is there a better way to do this?

I would like to have the control flow in my main. Something like this:

```
main()
   window1 = win2()
   window1.show()
   wait until button in window1 is clicked, then
   window1.close()

   window2 = win2()
   window2.show()
   wait until button in window2 is clicked, then
   window1.close()
   ....
```

Comment: Maybe you want a `QWizard`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use `QWizard` or `QStackedWidget` class to perform this task. You can easily switch between widgets or windows using either of these two classes. Refer to [QWizard](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwizard.html) and [QStackedWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html) docs.

Answer (score 0):

Qt provides special widget for such cases, which called [QWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html). Look at it. It's also available in Qt4.